# virtual boxes mirror reflection

Tags: reflection, geometry, lenses

The problem statement

> Find the lightpath with a given starting and ending points via one or more mirrors.

In those kind of problems you try image someone pointing a laser with a very narrow beam at a certain direction to the mirror, so it will reach point `B`.

For example:

You are seeing a square mirror room (with mirrored walls `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) where you point from point `A` via the mirrors `c`, `b`, `d` and `a`  to point `B`. A sketch can be made easily made:

[image: [IMG]http://i.imgur.com/QkWF4e6.png?2[/IMG]]

In order to find a more accurate solution, we flip the base cell with the points `A` and `B` a few times as shown in the image. After the mirroring is done, the line connecting `A`  is drawn towards the mirror image `B'`.

> Question: Construct the path in the original square. Complete the drawing.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LkjW29I.png]

**My confusion**

Why do I need to do with those virtual squares? I don't see an logical way to draw the reflections easily. And why is the line drawn from `A` to `B'` through all those other virtual rooms?

Answer (score 1):

Your drawing is incorrect.  The ray from A to surface c is not correctly reflected.  The particular 4 faces c, b, d, a, are sequentially hit without involving any face(s) parallel to the plane of the page, so we are seeing the plane projection of any three-D paths.

The Ac, bd, aB lines must be parallel, just as the cb, da lines are parallel.

Optics is applied geometry.   Freehand sketches don't work.